# Convert PID parameters to Q15 format

Tags: control-system, dsp, pid-controller, matlab

I have calculated the transfer function of my system to apply a PID to it. With MATLAB and the PID Tuner tool I got the `Kp`, `Ki` and `Kd` parameters of my PID controller. For example in my case they are 0.175, 371.22 and 0 respectively.

Now, I need to use this values in my DSP but the PID algorithm uses the Q15 fractional format for everything. I know how I should scale the input and output values of my PID:

- If the max input value is `x`, divide it by `x` if it goes from `-x` to `x`, or do `(x/2)-1` if it goes from `0` to `x` and then convert to Q15 fractional
- For the output value just scale it to your needs

But how do I convert my PID parameters `Kp`, `Ki` and `Kd` to Q15 correctly? If I apply some factor to them like I do for the input and output values I'm actually changing the loop response so how is this done? I think this should be a fairly common thing to do when designing digital PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

First at all the maximum representables values of the Q15 format are -1 and 0.9999. So you might have a problem with your Ki.

The most common solution for converting a double to a Q15 is to multiply it with 2^15.

I am usually using this macro:

```
#define Q15(x)(s16) ((x<0.0) ? (s16)(32768*(x) - 0.5):(s16)(32768*(x) + 0.5))
```

But because of your Ki is not working with the Q15 format you should use another Q-format. eg: Q6 or Q7.

For further information you could check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)).

Comment: So there's just no way to do it, I have to keep my parameters below 1?

Comment: Or you could shift your parameters only 6 times. (=Q6)

Comment: The code will keep working if it was designed to use with Q15 and I use Q6?

Comment: Just change the fraction length from 15 (32768) to 6 (64).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal matlab function: fi(v) to construct a fixed point numeric object: https://de.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/fi.html